# Use of ご and にね

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

In the following sentence, how are にね and ご used in that first clause. I'm baffled. They seem to have no meaning.

> で、そんな**ご**身分**にね**、一年も経てばいよいよ引け目を感じますよ。

Comment: On this site, using asterisks for bold doesn't always work correctly with Japanese, even when it looks okay in the preview.  As a workaround, you can use HTML tags.  (Click "edit" to see what it looks like, if you don't already know.)

Answer (score 2):

ご is just the honorific prefix 御. This person is talking to someone to whom he/she shows respect, and thus adds an honorable ご to that person's 身分.

The にね is the particle に plus the colloquial ね as in そうですね. So the sentence is saying that this person would feel weak after a year and punctuating it with colloquial patterns. That is, this is meant to imitate spoken rather than written Japanese.